# How to validate XML using SCH (schematron) and XSD in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xslt, xsd-validation, schematron

I'm generating e-invoicing XML files (CII D16B) using Python. These files comply with the EN16931 standard (https://github.com/ConnectingEurope/eInvoicing-EN16931).

I need to validate the generated XML against the schematron rules provided in the ConnectingEurope repository (eInvoicing-EN16931).

I'm having trouble finding information on performing schematron validation in Python.

I've tried using libraries like lxml, xmlschema, and saxonc (potentially requiring a license) along with the built-in xml library, but haven't been successful.

The complexity lies in the XML structure: it uses four different namespaces with intricate nested rules defined within a global schematron file (https://github.com/ConnectingEurope/eInvoicing-EN16931/blob/master/cii/schematron/EN16931-CII-validation.sch).

While online validation tools exist (e.g., https://ecosio.com/en/peppol-and-xml-document-validator/, https://invoice-portal.de/en/peppol-bis-xrechnung-validator/), I'd prefer to integrate validation within my Python script before generating the final XML.

Does anyone have experience with schematron validation in Python? Are there specific libraries or approaches recommended for this scenario, especially considering the multiple namespaces and nested rules?

Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks !

Comment: That is too general to allow us to help, if encounter a certain problem using e.g. SaxonC with a particular schematron schema and a particular XML instance  then ask a question telling us all details allowing us to understand and reproduce that particular problem and see whether we can make suggestions to fix it. The same for lxml, if you run into a particular problem then post that as a separate description. But as the Schematron has defined the query binding as xslt2 I doubt that lxml is the right tool for that Schematron, you need an XSLT 2 or 3 processor, which SaxonC 12 HE is.

Comment: For what's worth, I have run both the preprocessed complete Schematron schema https://github.com/ConnectingEurope/eInvoicing-EN16931/blob/master/cii/schematron/preprocessed/EN16931-CII-validation-preprocessed.sch through Schematron validation at my SaxonC 12 HE powered XML workbench https://saxonc-xmlworkbench.azurewebsites.net/ as well as simply run the provided precompiled https://github.com/ConnectingEurope/eInvoicing-EN16931/blob/master/cii/xslt/EN16931-CII-validation.xslt as XSLT, SaxonC manages that without problems, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Do you use SaxonC EE ?

Comment: For Schematron and XSLT and XQuery and XPath at https://saxonc-xmlworkbench.azurewebsites.net/ I use SaxonC 12 HE. I also do you SaxonC EE, if you want XSD validation from Saxon then indeed you need EE, or in the XSLT 3 world for schema-aware XSLT and for streamed XSLT. But XmlSchema is an alternative for XSD validation and its maintainer is usually responsive if you run into problems with a particular schema.